# How to add text label on the the video frame by frame - iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am doing video editing app. I have one  animation video and I am using AVPlayer to play the video. So i need to add some label text on the video frame by frame.

Is it possible to add overlay label text on the video frame by frame?

Comment: Give some more detail and also let us know what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you will have to use [AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation) to do this. However is can be complex with no previous knowledge of AVFoundation. The best thing I can do is to give you this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/188034/how-to-play-record-and-merge-videos-in-ios-and-swift) and then this [one](https://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos) (which is what you want to do but written in Objective-C). These tutorials will explain to you the basics of how the framework works. You can also check the Apple [videos](https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/) about the framework.